# How to cache signed files (Service worker)

Tags: javascript, service-worker

Several front-end applications implement a signature template in the files to control the cache, and each change in the file that signature changes.
How do I get the Service Worker to handle these signatures and cache?

Signature Examples:

- sw-d58e3582afa99040e27b92b13c8f2280.js
- sw.js?_gc=20180101

I'm working on an application that is already ready, trying to implement service worker for certain features to become available offline.

Example, in this section I need to say what I will cache, however, the application changes the signatures of the file to control the cache. (today it's like this)

```html
caches.open('my-cache').then(function(cache) {
return cache.addAll([
    '/index.html',
    '/styles.css',
    '/main.js'
]);})
```

The application is always changing "styles.css" to "styles.css? V = 1527624807103_1" (timestamp) As far as I understand, "styles.css" is not the same as "styles.css? V = 1527624807103_1".

Comment: its workbox but  reading this may help with your background on SW precache versioning  :: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-precaching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not version or add a signture parameter to the URL used for your actual, top-level service worker file. As explained in "[The Service Worker Lifecycle](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle#avoid_changing_the_url_of_your_service_worker_script)":

> It can land you with a problem like this:
>
> 1. index.html registers sw-v1.js as a service worker.
> 2. sw-v1.js caches and serves index.html so it works offline-first.
> 3. You update index.html so it registers your new and shiny sw-v2.js.
>
> If you do the above, the user never gets `sw-v2.js`, because
>   `sw-v1.js` is serving the old version of index.html from its cache.
>   You've put yourself in a position where you need to update your
>   service worker in order to update your service worker.

As for the actual URLs that are included inside of your service worker file, which may legitimately contain versioning/hashes/signatures, your best bet is to use a tool that integrates with your build process and will generate the list of URLs based on the latest versions of each file that should be precached.

[Workbox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/precache-files/) is one such tool, and there are others, like [`sw-precache`](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/sw-precache) (a precursor to Workbox), and [`offline-plugin`](https://github.com/NekR/offline-plugin).

Comment: Tks @Jeff Posnick, I'm going to get information about workbox and sw-precache.

Comment: I'm not using node or npm. Is it still possible to use one of these components?

Comment: You can use [`workbox-cli`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-cli) from any build process that allows running shell commands.